# Sum all of the numerical values in an arraylist of playing cards

Tags: java, arraylist, sum

Im trying to add up all of the numerical values in a randomly generated deck of cards but I am having some difficulties getting it to work.
So far i have:

```
public PackCards(int n) {
    Card c;
    pack = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        c = new Card();
        pack.add(c);
    }
}

public int totalPack() {
    int sum =0;
    for(int i = 0; i < pack.size(); i++)
    {
        sum = sum + pack.get(i);
    }

}
```

but this give me an error because i am trying to sum the arraylist of class card inestead of the cards numerical values, any idea how i can fix this? thanks

Comment: Have you read the error? It should give you a useful hint, including the line that is causing an issue and the reason for the issue...

Comment: Can you please give us your error?

Comment: It would be helpful to share the error.

Comment: `pack` is an `ArrayList` of `Card` objects, you are probably getting an error because you summing objects, not their numerical values.

Comment: You need a `return` statement in `totalPack`.

Comment: yeah sorry the error is because i am trying to sum the arraylist of class card inestead of the cards numerical values, any idea how i can fix this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's this line:

```
sum = sum + pack.get(i);
```

You have an ArrayList of class Card so get would be returning the object Card, not an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to say:

`sum = sum + pack.get(i).getCardValue()` or some such thing.  You can't add an int with a `Card` object...

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the cards to an integer before summing. Using streams makes this more obvious:

```
return pack.stream()
    .mapToInt(card -> card.getIntValue())
    .sum();
```